# Brace expansion substitution?

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

I've made a small bash script to automatically split my two monitors with imagemagick when I take a screenshot.

```
#! /bin/bash
convert "$1" -crop 1024x600+0+0 +repage "${1//.png/}-left.png"
convert "$1" -crop 1280x1024+1024+0 +repage "${1//.png/}-right.png"
```

This works great, but will only rename it properly if it's a png (which in this case isn't an issue). Is there anyway to make it work so it'd move the file extension to the end? So if I called this script (let's call it splitimage) on a file `oldscreenshot.jpg` it'd give me `oldscreenshot-left.jpg` and `oldscreenshot-right.jpg`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, using the `${param##word}` and `${param%word}` expansions.  The first will get rid of the extension, the last will get rid of everything *but* the extension

```
#! /bin/bash

convert "$1" -crop 1024x600+0+0 +repage "${1%.*}-left.${1##*.}"
convert "$1" -crop 1280x1024+1024+0 +repage "${1%.*}-right.${1##*.}"
```

#### Example

```
$ var=foo.jpg; echo "No extention: ${var%.*} | Extention only: ${var##*.}"
No extention: foo | Extention only: jpg
```

Comment: `image-1.5-final.png`

Answer (score 1):

Yes. But use stripping in your **parameter expansion** (*not* brace expansion, that's something completely different) instead of replacement.

```
convert "$1" -crop 1024x600+0+0 +repage "${1%.*}-left.${1##*.}"
```

Comment: Parameter expansion. I couldn't remember what it was called and thus couldn't search for it.